# how i can solve this error "A PHP Error was encountered"?

Tags: codeigniter

Please give some idea. how to solve the error?

```
        echo "<td class='bold'>Race Category<span class='star'>*</span></td>";
    $array_all=array('name'=>'race_category','value'=>$s_race_category,'type'=>'RACE_CATEGORY','style'=>"class='selectbox'",'javascript'=>'','default'=>'');
    echo "<td>";
    echo $this->model_students->getAll($array_all);
    echo "</td>";
```

The error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: s_race_category
Filename: templates/forms.php
Line Number: 46

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: s_programme
Filename: templates/forms.php
Line Number: 124
```

Comment: Where are you defining those variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The severity says "Notice", meaning they won't break your page but they indicate something else. In this case you probably haven't defined your variables before you use them.

try assigning a value to the variables like:

```
$s_race_category = "";
$s_programme = "";
```

You are seeing these notices because of the PHP error reporting level, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: i try retrieve data from the database. my doubt is already i created table, now i alert add this two columns. so its not retrieve the data.

Comment: i got it. Thank you for your help. After i saw your tips, i check my code and i didn't select the new fields in the "select query".